# WIX “if like statement” in component

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, installation

I’ve a WIX Setup for an asp.net application. The user can select whether the app pool should run under a build-in or a custom account (similar to the IIS advanced app pool settings>Identity).

After the user has finished the setup, the setup has to check whether the user has selected a build-in account or a custom account. 
The user has set the following properties during the setup:

**USE_BUILTIN_ACCOUNT**: True if the user has selected a built-in account, otherwise false

**BUILTIN_ACCOUNT**:     The name of the selected built-in account

**IDENTITY_NAME**:       The name of a custom user

Currently the setup works only with the custom name:

```
<Component Id="myAppPoolCmp" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
    <util:User Id="myAppPoolUser" CreateUser="no" Name="[IDENTITY_NAME]" Password="[IDENTITY_PWD]" Domain="[IDENTITY_DOMAIN]" />
</Component>
```

How can I change the setup, so it will use the name of the built-in or the custom account, based on the value of **USE_BUILTIN_ACCOUNT**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

The following code works for me:

```
<Component Id="sMatSupervisorAppPoolCmpBuiltIn" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
    <Condition><![CDATA[WEB_APP_POOL_USE_BUILTIN_ACCOUNT = "true"]]></Condition>
     <util:User Id="sMatSupervisorAppPoolUserBuiltIn" CreateUser="no" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_BUILTIN_ACCOUNTS]" />
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="x" Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" Identity="other" User="y" />
</Component>

<Component Id="sMatSupervisorAppPoolCmp" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
    <Condition><![CDATA[WEB_APP_POOL_USE_BUILTIN_ACCOUNT <> "true"]]></Condition>
    <util:User Id="sMatSupervisorAppPoolUser" CreateUser="no" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_NAME]" Password="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_PWD]" Domain="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_DOMAIN]" />
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="x" Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" Identity="other" User="y" />
</Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't wait until the end of setup to ask the user which they want to do.  You have to do it up front in the UI before the installation transaction starts (collect all data, point of no return ).

To implement you will likely use component conditions to create mutually exclusive components.

Comment: I’ve already collected the data. I’ve a dialog in which the user can select a built-in account or enter the name and password of another account. (The input of the user gets stored in the 3 properties described above.)
My question is… how can I select the account which the user has selected in the UI?
Something like:
`If(USE_BUILTIN_ACCOUNT)
    account = BUILTIN_ACCOUNT
else
    account = IDENTITY_NAME`